# Scale svg according to font size

Tags: pdftex, svg, inkscape

Assume this example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.75\textwidth}{!}{\includesvg{mysvg}}
  \caption{mycaption}
  \label{mylabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My .svg files are basically graphs generated from DOT format via GraphViz. Those graphs have labels. With the current method, those labels are written in the same font as the whole document, since the svg is converted to pdf+tex, but not in the same size. The current size of the figure is detemined by `{0.75\textwidth}`.

My question is: Is there any way to scale the figure according to the font size? It should be as big as it needs to be to have the labels of the graph written in the exact same size as the rest of the document.

Comment: An alternative would be to set the figure size, and scale the labels according to your text font.

Comment: How would I do that? I'd definitiely give it a try. But I think now the relation between graph size and label size fits (there are also node names IN the nodes), and that may be destroyed if I did that.

Comment: If your figures are convertet to pdf+tex, why do you include the svg files?

Comment: Because I wanted to avoid the step of manually converting them, ```includesvg``` does that automatically. Would what I want work if I converted them manually?

Comment: What happens when you try with `\includesvg[width=0.75\textwidth]{mysvg}` - *without* `\resizebox`?

Comment: It looks the same. I used the ```\resizebox``` to be able to scale it instead of defining a width, but I am not sure if it acutally makes a difference.

Comment: Is this still an open issue? If I read your question right, you either want to specify the size of your figure in relative units (like em) or Werner's comment should produce the desired behavior. If not, could you update your question to include a complete MWE (i.e. including the svg) and maybe point out what is wrong with a picture of the output?

Comment: I solved this somehow, but I absolutely don't remember how anymore 3,5 years after :D